# How to use interface to communicate between fragment and activity?

Tags: java, android, interface, nullpointerexception, fragment

I simply want to call a Fragment method from my MainActivity.

So I tried to use an Interface.

```
public interface MyInterface {
        void testMethod();
}
```

In my Fragment (TestFragment.java) I implement the interface and overrite the testMethod method.

```
@Override
public void testMethod() {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

but now I want to call this method from my MainActivity as soon as the onRewardedVideoCompleted get's called, but I'm not sure how to do it.
I tried it like this:

```
MyInterface myInterface = new TestFragment();
myInterface.testMethod();
```

But here I get an nullPointerException:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String
> android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
> Which reffers to the Toast message.

How do I call the method from my Interface in my MainActivity without getting an NullPointerException?

Thanks

Comment: You create a new fragment but not attach it to any activity. To show a Toast you need a context (in this case the activity that fragment has been attached to). Because the activity is `null`, so the app crashes.  You need to attach the fragment to an activity by using add/replace method of FragmentManager, then call the method of fragment directly. No need to use interface in this case.

Comment: @SonTruong I have to use an interface because I have an TabFragment which manages all sub fragments.
So in my MainActivity I use the FragmentManager to replace the ViewLayout with the TabFragment.
TabFragment contains 2 Fragments, I want to call a method inside one of those fragments and not from the TabFragment.
So it is not possible to use the FragmentManager in this case, isnt it?

Comment: Fragments are managed by Activity, Child Fragments are managed by Parent Fragments. If you want to call a method of a child fragment from an activity, then from the activity you call a method on the fragment, based on the action/data, the fragment will decide to call the corresponding method of child fragment. Interface will be useful when you want to call a method of a parent fragment from a child fragment, or call a method of an activity from a fragment. Because it will increase decoupling between activity/fragment and make fragment more reusable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create the interface for it like below

```
public interface FilterValuePassInterface {

    public void onSelectedFilterValue(String name);
}
```

Fragment class should look like below

```
class MyFragment extends Fragment implements FilterValuePassInterface {

   @Override
    public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        try {
            ((YOUR_ACTIVITY) getActivity()).setOnDataListener(this);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onSelectedFilterValue(String name) {

    }
}
```

And inside the `Activity` class , you need to create the method `setOnDataListener` and initialise the  fragment like below

```
 MyFragment myFragment;
    public void setOnDataListener(MyFragment myFragment) {

    this.myFragment = myFragment;

    }
```

Again inside the activity you can send the data from any click or event, you just need to call this method from the activity to transfer the data in fragment like below

```
    YOUR_CLICK.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

       public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        myFragment.onSelectedFilterValue("YOUR_MSG");

        }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access your method from Activity to Fragment. You do not need any interface. You just need to call the method from the fragment instance. However, if you want access Activity's method, you may use the interface.

```
public interface MyInterface {
        void testMethod();
}
```

And in your activity,

```
class MyActivity implements MyInterface{
void testMethod(){
}
}
```

in your fragment,

```
class MyFragment extends Fragment{
MyInterface myInterface;
public void onActivityCreated(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        if (getActivity() instanceof MyActivity) {
            myInterface = (MyInterface) getActivity();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface MyInterface {
    void testMethod();
}

class MyActivity implements MyInterface{
    public void testMethod(){
    }
}
```

Inside your main(), you can create a new object of MyActivity like this which will allow you to access the method:

```
MyActivity example= new MyActivity(); 
example.testMethod();
```